# Spark: stage X contains task of a very large size when running sc.binaryFiles()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to load ~1M file set stored on S3. When running `sc.binaryFiles("s3a://BUCKETNAME/*").count()`

I'm getting `WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (177 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB`. This is followed by failed tasks

I see that it infers 128 partitions for this stage, which is too low, note that when running the same command on 400K files bucket, number of partitions will be much higher (~2K partitions) and the action will succeed.

setting a higher `minPartitions` didn't help;
setting a higher `spark.default.parallelism` didn't help as well.

the only thing that worked was to create multiple smaller RDDs of 1000 files each, and running `sc.union` on them, Problem with this approach is that it's too slow.

How can this issue be mitigated?

UPDATE:
went on to see how number of partitions is settled in `BinaryFileRDD.getPartitions()` which got me to this piece of code:

```
  def setMinPartitions(sc: SparkContext, context: JobContext, minPartitions: Int) {
    val defaultMaxSplitBytes = sc.getConf.get(config.FILES_MAX_PARTITION_BYTES)
    val openCostInBytes = sc.getConf.get(config.FILES_OPEN_COST_IN_BYTES)
    val defaultParallelism = sc.defaultParallelism
    val files = listStatus(context).asScala
    val totalBytes = files.filterNot(_.isDirectory).map(_.getLen + openCostInBytes).sum
    val bytesPerCore = totalBytes / defaultParallelism
    val maxSplitSize = Math.min(defaultMaxSplitBytes, Math.max(openCostInBytes, bytesPerCore))
    super.setMaxSplitSize(maxSplitSize)
  }
```

I followed the computation and it still didn't make sense, I should get a much larger number.

So I tried to reduce the `config.FILES_MAX_PARTITION_BYTES` config (`spark.files.maxPartitionBytes`) - this did increase the number of partitions, and made the job finish, however I'm still getting the original warning (with a somewhat smaller task size), and still, the munber of partitions is way smaller than when running on a 400K file set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was rooted in the sizes of the files: To my surprise, the files in s3 were not uploaded properly, and their size was 100 times smaller than they should've been. This caused `setMinPartitions` to calculate splits that contained large amount of small files. Each split is essentially a comma separated string of file paths, since we have many files per split, we got a very long instruction string that should be communicated to all workers. This burdened the network and caused the entire flow to fail. Setting `spark.files.maxPartitionBytes` to a lower value solved the issue.